# Rails 4 and Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, cdn

So I was reading this article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31

In it, it says:

```
Heroku recommends using a CDN to speed up delivery of assets for the fastest visitor experience. If you are already using a CDN, then adding Rack::Cache will not speed up delivery of assets. If you do not wish to use a CDN, Rack::Cache is an good way to speed up asset delivery.
```

I guess my question is whether using any form of caching (in addition to the CDN that we're already using) such as russian-doll caching, would actually speed our application up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is talking about Rack::Cache, which caches your assets (images, js, css, etc.). You'll be able to speed up your application by implementing something like fragment caching (caching parts of your views that won't change too often) as [outlined here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#fragment-caching).

Comment: Thanks for the link :) But the question is about a CDN not caching stuff.